# Hibernate Composite Primary Key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have some problem with hibernate annotation. I have some scheme here:

### Table `feature_map`

1. `module_name` (PK) (FK `m_module_fk`)
2. `feature_code` (PK) (FK `m_feature_fk`)

### Table module

1. `module_name` (PK)

### Table feature

1. `feature_code` (PK)

---

I have tried several way from hibernate and other site, but it did not work.
Anyone who could me help this one?

### Edited

I'm sorry I did not tell you all the code. I mean, I asked you help with your own code to generate it into hibernate annotation code. Sorry it was my mistakes. I have the correct one, I found it last night. CMIIW.

Below are my code :

FeatureMap.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "M_FEATURE_MAP")
@IdClass(FeatureMapPk.class)
public class FeatureMap implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "module_name")
    private String moduleName;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "feature_code")
    private String featureCode;

    @MapsId("moduleName")
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "module_name", referencedColumnName = "module_name",
            insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Module module;

    @MapsId("featureCode")
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "feature_code", referencedColumnName = "feature_code",
            insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Feature feature;

    /*Getter Setter, hash equals and toString*/
}
```

FeatureMapPk.class

```
public class FeatureMapPk implements Serializable {

    private String moduleName;
    private String featureCode;

    public FeatureMapPk(){

    }

    public FeatureMapPk(String moduleName, String featureCode){
        this.moduleName = moduleName;
        this.featureCode = featureCode;
    }

    /*Getter Setter, hash equals and toString*/
}
```

Module.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "M_MODULE")
public class Module implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "module_name")
    private String moduleName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "module")
    private FeatureMap featureMap;

    /*Getter Setter, hash equals and toString*/
}
```

Feature.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "M_FEATURE")
public class Feature implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "feature_code")
    private String featureCode;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "feature")
    private FeatureMap featureMap;

    /*Getter Setter, hash equals and toString*/
}
```

Thank so much for answering :) 
I'm sorry before it was my mistakes.

Comment: you have some problem but don't say what use of annotations you tried and what was the result. And don't say "it didn't work", what is that supposed to mean, and what do you expect people to be able to tell you from no information?

Comment: If your FutureMap does not have any additional properties than the ones for the keys and module/map (in your code there is nothing else) than you dont need it at all. It is just a join-table which will be handled by JPA for you. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Mapping_a_OneToOne_Using_a_Join_Table Also are you sure that it is only OneToOne between module and feature (one module one feature, not many) it is like that in your current code.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the advice @zielu. I have another properties in FutureMap.class. I sure it was a one-to-one relationship. because futureMap will become an entity, not just a table that generated by many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can we actually help without seeing your code, the several ways you have tried and the actual schema not just Primary Keys.

Nevertheless, most likely you are not interested in composite key but simple OneToMany or ManyToMany mapping in Module and Feature and no Entity for FeatureMap.